# Why core session is empty?

Tags: module, magento-1, session, social-buttons, core-session

I have a custom module, which basically adds social media login in magento. However I am facing an issue with `core/session` which I dont know how to resolve.

I am adding my custom blocks in customer login page via my own layout xml file. Every block is loading successfully. One of my cusotm block is setting a variable in `core/session` through it's `_construct()` method as like this.

File : `app\code\local\Mynamespace/Mymodule/Block/Entity/Someblock.php`

```
<?php
class Mynamespace_Mymodule_Block_Entity_Someblock extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
     protected function _construct() {
        parent::_construct();

        // CSRF protection
        $csrf = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setGoogleCsrf($csrf);
        $this->client->setState($csrf);

    }

}
```

I ensured that, session variable is set when the page loads. Now in the next process/request, I need to validate `google_csrf` variable that is set in `core/session`. But the problem is `Mage_Core_Model_Session` appears to be empty in the next process. Suppose I need to validate session during the request of url `www.domain.com/frontname/google/connect`, then I checked `core/session` in the corresponding controller file like this.

File : `app\code\local\Mynamespace/Mymodule/controllers/GoogleController.php`

```
public function connectAction()
{
   print_r(Mage::getSingleton('core/session'));die();
}
```

But it outputs `Mage_Core_Model_Session` with no variable set in it. Why it happens like this?

**More info**: actually the block in question is used to show google button in frontend. When click on that button, it will force user to authenticate him with google account. I am checking `core/session` in the controller that processes the `redirect url`. I am getting the response successfully. But `core/session` that set before this action seems empty.

You have any thoughts about it ? Let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the controller processing the redirect URL may be getting the `core/session` model before the customer's session has been re-started.

`Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::preDispatch` starts the session back up by calling `Mage_Core_Model_Session::start` (inherited from `Mage_Core_Model_Session_Abstract_Varien`). This is responsible for starting or resuming a user's session, allowing the various session models to reconnect with their data.

Instantiating a session model before the controller's `preDispacth` has re-started the session will result in a session model that is empty. This may result from getting the instance in the controller's `_construct` method, even if it is only actually read from after `preDispatch`.

Comment: I am checking this variable inside the controller method.For an example, `redirect_url` looks like `www.domain.com/frontname/google/connect`. I am checking session inside `Mynamespace_Mymodule_GoogleController::connectAction()`, which I think processed after preDispatch method.

Answer (score 0):

If the request to your controller is done using an ajax call, then it will be a different session, with different session_id();

Try echo your session_id in your block where you set the session variable and in your controller and see if its the same.

Comment: No I am not using any ajax request for this. You have any other thoughts? Thanks for your time.